# Parse JSON using Linux bash shell and Underscore

Tags: json, linux, bash, underscore.js

The code below doesn't do what I need it to. I want to pass $STR to Underscore and pluck out the "name" attribute from the JSON data.

```
#!/bin/bash
STR='['$@']';
RESULT=`underscore pluck --data '+$STR+' name`;
echo $RESULT;
```

JSON Data:

```
{"maxResults":1,"resultList":[{"@class":"com.sohnar.trafficlite.transfer.crm.refactor.ClientCRMEntryTO","id":331458,"version":2,"dateCreated":"2017-05-31T13:20:22.960+0000","dateModified":"2017-06-05T14:23:59.961+0000","lastUpdatedUserId":71954,"name":"ACME_CLIENT","website":null,"description":null,"billingLocation":null,"primaryLocation":null,"crmEntryType":"CLIENT","industryType":null,"accountManagerId":103049,"crmClientClassificationListItemId":{"id":12405},"companyProfile":{"id":486024,"version":1,"dateCreated":"2017-05-31T13:20:22.960+0000","dateModified":"2017-06-05T14:23:59.962+0000","sourceOfBusinessListItemId":null,"creditTermsListItemId":{"id":4215},"relationshipSince":"2017-05-30T23:00:00.000+0000","turnover":0,"employees":0,"taxNumber":null,"companyNumber":null,"nominalCode":null,"accountPackageId":null,"optOutMarketing":false,"optOutEmail":false,"optOutTelephone":false,"notes":null},"colorCode":0,"externalCode":"SAP-01","clientState":"CLIENT","defaultCustomRateSetId":null,"preferredCurrencyId":{"id":48},"freeTags":[]}],"windowSize":5,"currentPage":1}
```

Comment: `$STR` is not expanded within single-quotes. Replace `'+$STR+'` with `"+$STR+"`

Comment: I get the following error when I do that:

"Error while parsing '--data' argument in mode 'lax': Invalid or unexpected token".

Comment: Can you edit the post and include the command you run, the actual result and the expected result?

Comment: You're spreading valid JSON data out over *multiple* arguments, in such a way that concatenating those arguments with spaces between them results a usable document? Edit your question to show a real use case so we don't need to make so many assumptions about the data.

Answer (score 2):

Several problems here.  First you should use double quotes, not single.   Double quotes allows the expansion of variable.  Second, I am assuming that you don't want the `+` as part of the data - they are not a string concatenation operator in bash (there is no need for one).

```
str="[$@]"
result=$(underscore pluck --data "$str" name)
echo $result
```

I used the $( ) notation rather than back-ticks ( `` ). Back-ticks are considered deprecated and difficult to read.

I have replaced uppercase variable names with lower case. This is because there are many uppercase variable names used by the shell so using uppercase risks a name collision. Best to use lower or mixed-case variable names.

I have also removed the superfluous semi-colons `;`.  They are not doing any harm, but they are of no use either.  In bash a semi-colon is a *statement separator*, whereas in languages like C and Java they are a statement terminator.

Edit:  double-quoted `$@`

Comment: I get the following result from that with the change of "$str" to   '"$str"' adding single quotes before and after. The result is now: [null, null, null, null]

Comment: Are the single quotes part of the data to be passed to `underscore`?  What are you passing in to `$@`?  What value do you expect?  What is `underscore`?

Comment: The reason I was getting [null, null, null, null] is because it was treating my input as a string literal.

Comment: Probably want to double quote `$@` as well

Comment: @123 - I'm getting Error while parsing '--data' argument in mode 'lax': Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: If not a string literal, then what do you need?  You can only pass strings on a command-line.  What is the purpose of the `[` `]`?  When you say double-quote, do the quotes have to be passed into `underscore`?  What is `underscore` and do you have any documentation for it?

Comment: $@ contains JSON data passed into the script.

Comment: @cdarke Could write the assignment as just `str="[$@]"`

Comment: @Berni Post example JSON data that could be contained in `str` in your question.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest `str="[$*]"` instead -- that's actually explicit about what it's doing, whereas `str="[$@]"` implies that the user wants argument boundaries to be retained.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  you are right of course.  I was incremental in my editing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$(underscore select .name --outfmt text < get.crm.client.acme.json)
echo $name
```

Comment: Well what was all that with `$@` in your question then?  If you had told us that the `underscore` program read JSON from stdin we could have saved a lot of time.